# finding shared column information - a least common ancestor question

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame object consisting of columns of information that is tree-like. For instance, I have performed a search of a set of features (`query_name`) and returned a set of potential matches (`match_name`). Every match has an associated location that is split into `continent`, `country`, `region`, and `town`.

The problem I'd like to resolve is finding, for a given `query_name`, the location information that all potential matches have in common.

For example, with this bit of example data:

```
query_name <- c(rep("feature1", 3), rep("feature2", 2), rep("feature3", 4))
match_name <- paste0("match", seq(1:9))
continent <- c(rep("NorthAmerica", 3), rep("NorthAmerica", 2), rep("Europe", 4))
country <- c(rep("UnitedStates", 3), rep("Canada", 2), rep("Germany", 4))
region <- c(rep("NewYork", 3), "Ontario", NA, rep("Bayern", 2), rep("Berlin", 2))
town <- c("Manhattan", "Albany", "Buffalo", "Toronto", NA, "Munich", "Nuremberg", "Berlin", "Frankfurt")

data <- data.frame(query_name, match_name, continent, country, region, town)
```

We'd generate this data.frame object:

```
    query_name match_name    continent      country  region      town
1   feature1     match1 NorthAmerica UnitedStates NewYork Manhattan
2   feature1     match2 NorthAmerica UnitedStates NewYork    Albany
3   feature1     match3 NorthAmerica UnitedStates NewYork   Buffalo
4   feature2     match4 NorthAmerica       Canada Ontario   Toronto
5   feature2     match5 NorthAmerica       Canada    <NA>      <NA>
6   feature3     match6       Europe      Germany  Bayern    Munich
7   feature3     match7       Europe      Germany  Bayern Nuremberg
8   feature3     match8       Europe      Germany  Berlin    Berlin
9   feature3     match9       Europe      Germany  Berlin Frankfurt
```

I'm hoping to get advice on how to construct a function that will produce the result below. Note that shared location information is now concatenated and separated with a `;` delimiter.

- Feature1 differs only at the `town` information, thus the returned string contains the `continent` through `region` information.
- Feature2 doesn't *differ* at `region` or `town` in the two matches here because one of the two matches contains no information. Nevertheless, lack of information is considered distinct from values with information, so the only thing shared in common for feature2 matches are `continent` and `country`.
- Feature3 contains shared `continent` and `country` information, but distinct `region` and `town`, so just `continent` and `country` are retained.

Hoping for an output file that looks like this:

```
query_name   location_output
feature1    NorthAmerica;UnitedStates;NewYork;
feature2    NorthAmerica;Canada;;
feature3    Europe;Germany;;
```

Thanks for any advice you can spare.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    gather(key, val, -query_name, -match_name) %>%
    select(-match_name, -key) %>%
    group_by(query_name, val) %>%
    add_count() %>%
    group_by(query_name) %>%
    filter(n == max(n)) %>%
    summarise(location_output = paste0(unique(val[!is.na(val)]), collapse = ";"))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  query_name location_output
#  <fct>      <chr>
#1 feature1   NorthAmerica;UnitedStates;NewYork
#2 feature2   NorthAmerica;Canada
#3 feature3   Europe;Germany
```

Answer (score 0):

This is less elegant than @MauritsEvers' solution (it doesn't automatically take care of an arbitrary number of levels), but it ensures that every `location_output` has all four `;` delimiters.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(query_name) %>%
  summarize(continent = ifelse(n_distinct(continent) == 1, first(continent), ""),
            country = ifelse(n_distinct(country) == 1, first(country), ""),
            region = ifelse(n_distinct(region) == 1, first(region), ""),
            town = ifelse(n_distinct(town) == 1, first(town), "")) %>%
  mutate(location_output = paste(continent, country, region, town, sep = ";")) %>%
  select(query_name, location_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lapply(split(data, data$query_name), function(x){
    x = x[,-(1:2)]
    r = rle(sapply(x, function(d) length(unique(d))))
    x[1, seq(r$lengths[1])]
})
#$feature1
#     continent      country  region
#1 NorthAmerica UnitedStates NewYork

#$feature2
#     continent country
#4 NorthAmerica  Canada

#$feature3
#  continent country
#6    Europe Germany
```